# Specify resources allowed to call a function in its AWS SAM Function template

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sam

**TL; DR:** How should I edit the template below so that it can be triggered by a user pool trigger?

I try to crate a CloudFormation template for a Lambda function defining both the services the function can call and be called from. It should be run with a Cognito User Pool trigger.

To do that, I've defined a resource in template of type `AWS::Serverless::Function` briefly as follows. Watch out the `Policies` section:

```
Resources:
  MyFunctionResource:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: MyFunctionName
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
      MemorySize: 128
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 3
      Policies:
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "cognito-idp:*"
                - "logs:*"
                ...
              Resource: "*"
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
              Principal:
                Service: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:MyFunctionName"
```

The second policy I have inserted for restricting the resources can call my function fails during the stack creation:

> Policy document should not specify a principal. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

When I remove that *policy with principal*, the access to the function through the user pool trigger is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the permissions should be created as a separate resource with type [`AWS::Lambda::Permission`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) which can take the function name or arn it will be attached to.

Thus, the following logic creates the function with permissions (a.k.a. Function Policy) successfully:

```
Resources:
  MyFunctionResource:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: MyFunctionName
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
      MemorySize: 128
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 3
      Policies:
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "cognito-idp:*"
                - "logs:*"
                ...
              Resource: "*"
## Remove this section
#       - Version: "2012-10-17"
#         Statement:
#           - Effect: Allow
#             Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
#             Principal:
#               Service: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
#             Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:MyFunctionName"

## Add this instead
  MyFunctionPermissions:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt MyFunctionResource.Arn
      Principal: "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:userpool/*"
```